# quotient map of locally compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

Suppose $X,Y$ are non-compact locally comapct Hausdorff spaces,suppose we have a quotient map $Q:X\to Y$,can we conclude that $Q$ is proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Let $Q(x,y)=x$.

It is not proper as $Q^{-1}(0)\cong\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No, the function is $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.